# Apply conditional formatting to whole row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styling, conditional-formatting

I want to apply conditional format to whole row in dataframe in which there are many rows named `Total`

```
def highlight_total(s):
    is_total=s=='Total'
    return['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in is_total]

df.style.apply(highlight_total)
```

But it is highlighting only the `Total` cell not full row

Comment: You try looping through the "Total" row and highlight each value. It would be helpful if you could include how your data frame is formatted.

Comment: | 1 | Total |  100| 200 | 300 | This is how my df look, I want to highlight not only Total cell but 1,2, and 3 also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your DataFrame contains:

```
   Title   v1   v2   v3
1  Xxxx1   20   30   40
2  Yyyy1   80  170  260
3  Total  100  200  300
4  Xxxx2   70  120  210
5  Yyyy2  120  190  240
6  Total  190  310  450
```

Then, to highlight the whole row with *Title* of *'Total'*:

1. Define the following function:

   ```
   def rowStyle(row):
       if row.Title == 'Total':
           return ['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)
       return [''] * len(row)
   ```
2. Run: `df.style.apply(rowStyle, axis=1)` (I assume that you use
   *Jupyter Notebook*).

For the above data I got:

[image]

If you want to highlight also the index column, run:

```
df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': ''}).style\
    .apply(rowStyle, axis=1).hide_index()
```

Comment: Thanks alot for providing solution, but  when I am converting my df to .csv or .xlsx, conditional formatting is not showing there,

Comment: Of course, this formatting is visible only in *Jupyter Notebook*. You didn't write that you want such formatting in an *Excel* file. Maybe it is material for another question, but don't forget to mention that you want this formatting in Excel file.